# Getting the below error while trying to run a spring boot gradle project using weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to convert a spring project to spring boot project and when I try to run the project getting some issues.

Project version details:

- **JDK 11**
- **Spring Boot 2.6.4**
- **Gradle 6.8**

Here is the error I am facing while running the project.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)

<11-Mar-2024, 5:57:48,703 PM India Standard Time> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener failed: java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:119)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:720)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<11-Mar-2024, 5:57:48,757 PM India Standard Time> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "431416525593500" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

here is my files
**web.xml** `webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>insights-index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

`weblogic.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>insightstats</wls:context-root>
    <wls:weblogic-version>14.1.1.0</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:session-descriptor>
        <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
        <wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>false</wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>
    </wls:session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Here are the dependencies in `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.6.4', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '2.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version: '2.6.4'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-parser', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-script', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-transcoder', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-svg-dom', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-util', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-xml', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-svggen', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-gvt', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-dom', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-css', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-ext', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-awt-util', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-bridge', version: '1.6.1'

    implementation group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.7.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    implementation group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '1.8'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.0.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.3.0'
    implementation group: 'net.sf.ezmorph', name: 'ezmorph', version: '1.0.1'

    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-appengine', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-gson', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-jackson2', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-java6', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-servlet', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-analytics', version: 'v3-rev116-1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-appengine', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-gson', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-jackson2', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-jdo', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-appengine', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-java6', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-servlet', version: '1.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.kaptcha', name: 'kaptcha', version: '2.3'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5', name: 'httpclient5', version: '5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.core5', name: 'httpcore5', version: '5.2'

    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.13.3'

    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.1.3'

    implementation group: 'jfree', name: 'jcommon', version: '1.0.16'
    implementation group: 'jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.0.13'

    implementation group: 'com.tdunning', name: 'json', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'

    implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.3'
    implementation group: 'org.w3c.css', name: 'sac', version: '1.3'
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

    implementation group: 'taglibs', name: 'standard', version: '1.1.2'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-api', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-autotag-core-runtime', version: '1.1.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-compat', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-core', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-el', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-extras', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-freemarker', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-jsp', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-mvel', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-ognl', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-api', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-freemarker', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-jsp', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-mustache', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-servlet', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-servlet-wildcard', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-velocity', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-request-mustache', version: '1.0.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-servlet', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-template', version: '3.0.5'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tiles', name: 'tiles-velocity', version: '3.0.5'

    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.1.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.1.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])

    task deploy (dependsOn: war){
        copy {
            from "$buildDir/libs"
            into "war"
            include "*.war"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert the spring mvc project to spring boot project.

I checked and added all the dependencies needed for the migration and tried will different files and created `springconfigurations.java`,`configProperties.java`,`bootgradleapplicatoin.java` and all the needed files.

here are some of them in old web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
     <!-- white space remover filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>trimFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.cj.trim.trimFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>     
   <filter>  
  <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
   </filter> 
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     
     <!-- white space filter mapping -->
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>trimFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>pdfgeochart</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/pdfgeochart</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>pdfgeochart</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>insight.servlet.PdfGeoChartServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
        
    <filter-mapping>  
     <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>insights-index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
    <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Weblogic ships with its own SPring version (at least it did) make sure you configure your application to use Application classes before Server classes. Not sure which classloading feature that is.

Comment: The error hints at incompatible versions (at least that is my guess). What does your dependencies look like? What does your configuration look like? If you had a running application, why move all the configuration to Spring Boot instead of focussing on getting the application to run with the existing configuration and then take babysteps to improve.

Comment: Added the dependencies of the gradle file and added the whole error I am getting in the console for better view.

Comment: Are you adding the spring boot and dependency plugin? You should, and then remove the versions from the Spring Boot dependencies as those will then be automatically managed. The `jackson-core` one is pretty old as well and Spring Boot already pulls in a newer version. I also wonder what you had before moving to Spring Boot (in your web.xml) and why you decided to remove it. Also make sure you are following the documented steps for creating a Spring Boot based War for traditional deployment.

Comment: added the old web.xml file

Comment: I also wonder what jars are in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` why are you manually adding jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would revert all the work you have done and start fresh and take small steps. After each step verify if you still have a fully functional application.

1. First use Spring Boot to only manage your dependencies
2. Create an `@SpringBootApplication` class which uses `@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml")` (this will re-use your existing working configuration). Remove the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` from the `web.xml`.
3. Remove the `CharacterEncodingFilter` and move the other filters to a Java configuration or your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.
4. Move the `PdfGeoChartServlet` and a `ServletRegistrationBean` to your configuration or `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

You now have a Spring Boot application that still should work **and** re-uses your existing configuration. Now and just now start looking at your `spring-config.xml` with what you can move to Spring Boot. Easy to do are the `DataSource`, maybe some web configuration (views etc. etc.).

But do 1 thing at a time and verify each step.

Trying to do all this at once will lead to hard to debug problems as it could have been caused  by a multitude of other preceding steps. The important thing is thus small steps and verify each step. Ideally you have some integration tests in place.

A time ago I wrote [a blog](https://deinum.biz/2019-06-21-Upgrade-Spring-Framework-In-Existing-Application/) on upgrading Spring (but applies to other libraries as well) the procedure applies to moving to Spring Boot as well.

Comment: Thank you for the solution so now I am not getting error and weblogic is also connecting fine and but when I try to click the links in the website they are going to Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Check your logs, there should be an error in there, however that is a different question and could be due to parts of your configuration.

Comment: NO error logs and on screen I am getting this

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 12 15:16:39 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Comment: If you get an error there should be something in your logs. But you get a 404 meaning something cannot be found. But as stated that is a different question, your application deploys to weblogic what this question was about. We shouldn't start abusing comments to answer a new question.