# Getting Whitelabel Error Page when I run my spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, weblogic

I converted a spring project to a spring boot project and when I try to run the project the index page is coming fine and when I click any link it's just moving to a white label page error

```
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 12 15:16:39 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Project version details:

- **JDK 11**
- **Spring Boot 2.6.4**
- **Gradle 6.8**
- **WebLogic 14c**

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwju1.png)

Tried checking logs but no logs are visible and no sight of error.

my **`web.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>insights-index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

my **`weblogic.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>14.1.1.0</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>insightstats</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:session-descriptor>
        <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
        <wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>false</wls:http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>
    </wls:session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

here is the thing I am getting in the console

```
<14-Mar-2024, 2:09:01,246 PM India Standard Time> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101105> <[ServletContext@137153789[app:insights module:insights path:null spec-version:4.0]] error-page location: "/error.html" for the error-code: "404" does not exist. Serving the default error page.> 
<14-Mar-2024, 2:12:39,174 PM India Standard Time> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101105> <[ServletContext@90962557[app:insights module:insights path:null spec-version:4.0]] error-page location: "/error.html" for the error-code: "404" does not exist. Serving the default error page.>
```

Comment: Enable debug logging and check which URL is getting the 404 and what is happening in your application.

Comment: that did not work no logs are being printed

Comment: I doubt that there are no logs when you enable debug logging. There should be something in your servers logs.

Comment: There are no server logs also same as the console logs

Comment: As stated I doubt it unless you did something very wrong and destroyed all logging.

Comment: Added the logs I am getting in the console and the mapping of every page is not working and going to a error page and these were displaying in the console.

Comment: That is only the indication that there is no `error.html`. There must be something else especially if you turned on trace or debug logging for the application. There should be loads of logging.

Comment: @M.Deinum I solved it can you check the other one I have posted here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78140472/getting-the-below-error-while-trying-to-run-a-spring-boot-gradle-project-using-w